# Continuous Music Embed between pages

Tags: html, embed

I know this is not a widely favorable feature, but I've had to add a continuous music player to a web project of mine, at a client's insistence. Does anyone have a solution to keep the music playing continuously between pages? The client wants it to auto-play. The solution I have currently uses I-frames, but it's clunky – the pages don't have a unique URL, and the site does not properly come up in thumbnail on social networking sites, because everything is buried in a frame.

So far, I've tried:

A voluntary pop-up window that the user clicks on to start the player. Client did not like this because the music doesn't auto-play. I'm afraid having an automatic pop-up would be hidden by most browsers.

A flash music player that remembers where the user last left off on a song file, and loads from there the next time it is called for – unfortunately there are gaps in the playback (since the player has to be reloaded with every new page,) and the client is not satisfied.

The I-frame solution I have currently.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery and ajax to dynamically load in your content ie you have a "container" page which you then use ajax to pull in various content so it looks like you moving to "another" page

Comment: And use History API to handle keep the URL current.